# Testing a JPA application that uses multiple datasources

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I have an application that reads records from one database, does things to them, creates new records, and writes them to a new database.

The ecosystem uses EJB (tomEE) and JPA (openJPA), and tests using arquillian.

I have a persistence.xml with two peristence units, each of which uses a different datasource. The two datasources are defined in arquillian.xml

The tests fail, because Arquillian appears to have trouble with multiple persistence units (See, for example, this: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252186)

Is there some other approach I could use to automate testing of this application?

Comment: one could argue why are you testing jpa?  unit tests should be testing business logic, not whether third party facilities are working properly.

Comment: It's an integration test -- to verify that the end-to-end behavior, which is to create records in database2 that are derived from database1 -- works according to design spec.